# How to return values from a RecordSet outside the Class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access, qt4, recordset

I am trying to print a value fetched by using a RecordSet.

If I print the value form the RecordSet inside the method, it works just fine.
But if I return the value from that method, then it returns something like:

```
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.Field instance at 0x38897624>
```

Please suggest how to return the value correctly.
I want the value of the global variable 'data' before displaying the form as I need to assign its value to self.RollNo (QLineEdit).
The code is below:

```
import sys
import os
from win32com.client import Dispatch
from adoconstants import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class Form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Form,self).__init__(parent)

        self.RollNo = QLineEdit()
    ....
    ....

    def launch(self):
        oConn = Dispatch('ADODB.Connection')
        oConn.ConnectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=C:\Users\DELL\Student DB.accdb;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;"
        oConn.Open()

        if oConn.State == adStateOpen:
            oRS = Dispatch('ADODB.RecordSet')
            oRS.ActiveConnection = oConn
            oRS.Open("Select LAST(Enrollment_Number) from Student_Info")
            global data
            data = oRS.Fields.Item(0) # number 53 is fetched from the last record of Enrollment_Number field
            print data
            return data
            oRS.Close()
            oRS = None
        else:
            print "Connection Failed"
        if oConn.State == adStateOpen:
            oConn.Close()
        oConn = None

app=QApplication(sys.argv)
form=Form()
print form.launch()
app.exec_()
```

Result:

```
53
<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library.Field instance at 0x38897624>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you don't change value of data in your code somewhere?
Try to return int(data) to see if this result still exists. Like this:

```
...
 if oConn.State == adStateOpen:
            oRS = Dispatch('ADODB.RecordSet')
            oRS.ActiveConnection = oConn
            oRS.Open("Select LAST(Enrollment_Number) from Student_Info")
            global data
            data = oRS.Fields.Item(0) # number 53 is fetched from the last record of Enrollment_Number field
            print data
            return int(data)
            oRS.Close()
            oRS = None
...
```

Tell me if it works.